# Vimeo api get user collection

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Is there a way using vimeo api to retrieve user collections?

For example here is the link to user which show some showcases, channels, groups..

https://vimeo.com/cameranera/collections

I cant find anyhting similar in here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/users